# Error in conducting SQL queries using RODBC or ODBC with DBI

Tags: r, odbc, dbi, rodbc

I got an error when I was using RODBC (or ODBC and DBI) to conduct SQL queries.

The error message is

```
"Error in odbcQuery(channel, query, rows_at_time) : 
  'Calloc' could not allocate memory (214748364800 of 1 bytes)".
```

The funny thing is there is no issues when I query to 80% of my tables. The error only happens when I conduct queries in several table (small one). And also I will not get error if I conduct queries by joining the tables, though I will get an error if I just want to query data from the single table. Please have a look at my example

My code is listed below

```
library("RODBC") 

RODBC_connection <- odbcDriverConnect(paste('Driver={SQL Server};server=CA649028;database=CDNSW_Blank;trusted_connection=true', sep = ""))

# Load data from SQL query 
dt1 <- sqlQuery(channel=RODBC_connection, query = "SELECT * FROM country ") 
dt2 <- sqlQuery(channel=RODBC_connection, query = "SELECT * FROM state") 
# Above two lines will give the error 
Error in odbcQuery(channel, query, rows_at_time) : 
  'Calloc' could not allocate memory (214748364800 of 1 bytes)

dt2 <- sqlQuery(channel=RODBC_connection, query = "SELECT CountryName, StateName
                                                    From country c
                                                    LEFT JOIN state s ON s.CountryId = 
                                                    c.CountryId") 
# This query will success without any issue. 

##########################################################
# Query using odbc and DPI
library(dplyr) 
library(dbplyr) 
library(odbc) 
library(DBI) 

DBI_Connection <- dbConnect(odbc(),                        
                            driver = "SQL Server",                       
                            server = "CA649028",                                           
                            database = "CDNSW_Blank"
) 

dt1<- DBI::dbGetQuery(DBI_Connection, "SELECT * from country")
dt2<- DBI::dbGetQuery(DBI_Connection, "SELECT * from state")
*# Above two lines will give the error *
*Error in odbcQuery(channel, query, rows_at_time) : *
*  'Calloc' could not allocate memory (214748364800 of 1 bytes)*

dt3<- DBI::dbGetQuery(DBI_Connection, "SELECT CountryName, StateName
                                                    From country c
                                                    LEFT JOIN state s ON s.CountryId = 
                                                    c.CountryId")

 # This query will success without any issue.
```

The outputs of schema from the tables of country and state are as below

[image]

```
table_name  column_name data_type   column_default  character_maximum_length    numeric_precision
country CountryId   int NULL    NULL    10
country CountryName varchar NULL    128 NULL
country CountryCode varchar NULL    12  NULL
country CountryNote varchar NULL    255 NULL
country CountryAcronym  varchar NULL    8   NULL
country CountryFactor   nvarchar    NULL    -1  NULL
country CountryGeometry geometry    NULL    -1  NULL
country CreatedBy   varchar ('dba') 32  NULL
country DateCreated datetime    (getdate()) NULL    NULL
country ModifiedBy  varchar (NULL)  32  NULL
country DateModified    datetime    (NULL)  NULL    NULL
state   StateId int NULL    NULL    10
state   StateName   varchar NULL    64  NULL
state   StateCode   varchar NULL    12  NULL
state   StateAcronym    varchar NULL    8   NULL
state   CountryId   int NULL    NULL    10
state   StateFactor nvarchar    NULL    -1  NULL
state   StateGeometry   geometry    NULL    -1  NULL
state   CreatedBy   varchar ('dba') 32  NULL
state   DateCreated datetime    (getdate()) NULL    NULL
state   ModifiedBy  varchar (NULL)  32  NULL
state   DateModified    datetime    (NULL)  NULL    NULL
```

Comment: FYI, the `"SQL Server"` driver is rather ancient, I suggest installing the newest from Microsoft, and using `driver="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"`.

Comment: What are the schema of the two tables `country` and `state`? One quick way to know this is to run `select table_name, column_name, data_type, column_default, character_maximum_length, numeric_precision from information_schema.columns where table_name in ('country','state')`. (Please post the output from that into your question.)

Comment: After I followed your suggestion to change the driver from "SQL sever" into "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server". The problem fixed
Thank @r2evans